# Is there an R function to limit sum of numbers to 100 maintaining the original ratio

Tags: math, statistics, scale, normalization

I am new to R and math. I want to know if there is a function which will scale numeric vector to 100. I have a vector of percentages as numbers, I have to make sure the sum is 100. If the sum is not 100, the numbers need to be scaled up or down such that the ratio is maintained and the sum is 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Sum the numbers; call that T
2. compute C = 100/T
3. Multiply every number by C.

The new numbers then sum to 100 and are in the same ratios as the original numbers.